# With Synaptics "clickpad," AreaBottomEdge prevents right-clicking

Tags: xorg

I have a new Sony Vaio Z with what I believe they're calling a "Clickpad".  That is, it's a touchpad with a single physical button beneath, and the detected location of the click is used, in software, to determine whether the click is a left-, right-, center-, or other-click.

The touchpad has two parts:

[image: Sony Vaio Z touchpad]

The upper, textured part, is the 'touch' area (at least in Windows 7), and the lower, smooth part, has the physical button beneath.  (The little gadget in the bottom center is a fingerprint reader, if anyone is curious).

In Linux, I found that when I was clicking, my mouse cursor was moving, due to the entire area (both textured and smooth) being touch-sensitive.  I solved this problem with the following synaptics option:

```
AreaBottomEdge=3800
```

The problem with this is that now when I right-click, the synaptics driver seemingly doesn't pass along any finger-position information, because I am touching 'below' the 3800 boundary.

If I touch lightly in the lower right corner of the textured area while clicking it does register a right-click.  So this tells me that at least the "Clickpad" features are working properly.

So my question is: Is there any way to get a right-click on the smooth area to register as a click, without making it fully sensitive to motion detection?

I'm guessing this situation probably just calls for submitting an upstream feature request...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm guessing this situation probably just calls for submitting an upstream feature request...

[This (Debian) bug report](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=597082) contains a patch and some pointers to the upstream discussion, might be helpful here.

Comment: Despite my earlier comment, I tried this patch out of desperation, and while it's not perfect, it's a step in the right direction.  And it appears to be the latest development in this area (sad, that there has been _zero_ work in this area in the last year!)